# Flexi Auth login issue on online server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using flexi auth on wamp server.

Locally it is working fine but on online server I cannot take login.

I get the following error message.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: core/Input.php

Line Number: 389

Backtrace:

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Flexi_auth_model.php
Line: 2335
Function: set_cookie

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Flexi_auth_model.php
Line: 1746
Function: regenerate_ci_session_id

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Flexi_auth_model.php
Line: 1599
Function: set_login_sessions

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/libraries/Flexi_auth.php
Line: 61
Function: login

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Auth_model.php
Line: 64
Function: login

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/controllers/Ewall_pk.php
Line: 67
Function: login

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)

Filename: core/Input.php

Line Number: 389

Backtrace:

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Flexi_auth_model.php
Line: 2335
Function: set_cookie

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Flexi_auth_model.php
Line: 1746
Function: regenerate_ci_session_id

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Flexi_auth_model.php
Line: 1599
Function: set_login_sessions

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/libraries/Flexi_auth.php
Line: 61
Function: login

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Auth_model.php
Line: 64
Function: login

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/controllers/Ewall_pk.php
Line: 67
Function: login

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)

Filename: core/Input.php

Line Number: 389

Backtrace:

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Flexi_auth_model.php
Line: 1902
Function: set_cookie

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Flexi_auth_model.php
Line: 1752
Function: insert_database_login_session

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Flexi_auth_model.php
Line: 1599
Function: set_login_sessions

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/libraries/Flexi_auth.php
Line: 61
Function: login

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Auth_model.php
Line: 64
Function: login

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/controllers/Ewall_pk.php
Line: 67
Function: login

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 564

Backtrace:

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/models/Auth_model.php
Line: 70
Function: redirect

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/application/controllers/Ewall_pk.php
Line: 67
Function: login

File: /home/ewallpkc/public_html/test/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Comment: So are you running this in a subfolder called test. That will be different to how you were running it locally...

Comment: yes you are absolutely right sir. but I changed that in .htaccess file to test folder already.

Comment: ok guys. it was actually php version which was causing problem. anyways thanks to all